# remove html tags which is inside p tags because i am having issue in instant article

Tags: php, regex, facebook

Facebook doesn't allow one to add another html tags inside p tags.if i am adding it then i am getting below error

**General Errors: Empty Articles: You have one or more articles without any content.**

if i understand it properly then it is because of adding html tags inside p tags.where Facebook only allows text inside p tags.so can anyone please help me in solving this problem.

examples :

```html
<p><br></p>
```

> 

```html
<p><figure></figure></p>
```

Comment: you should not tag this into MySQL

Comment: @krishnpatel i am getting this tags from content which i have stored in database.

Comment: there is not issue with database in your question. if you don't get desire result from database. means problem with MySQL than you should tag it there.

Comment: Those examples supposed to be accurate? So you have paragraphs with other elements in them, but all of them including the paragraphs are “empty” when it comes to _actual_ (text) content? Then you should filter that stuff out.

Comment: What should happen to `<p><b>Keep this?</b>and this?<b>what about this</b></p>`

Answer (score 0):

I've only tested this in javascript but I think this should work in PHP too:

```
$html = '<p><figure></figure></p>';
$var = $html;

do {
    $html = $var;
    $var = preg_replace('(<p\b[^>]*>[^<]*)((?=<\/p>)|<[^>]+>)', '$1', $html);
} while($var != $html)
```

The only problem with this regex is that it won't properly remove nested `<p>` tags however these occurring seems unlikely.

Comment: @kirangadhvi How about now?

Comment: didn't get any solution yet.

Comment: yeah i know it but it's still the same that's what i mean.